# Max length of varchar / text in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to find the answer to a simple question.
Let say I have a table which I store content in it.
The content is just a string.
I am trying to find what is my max length for this specific one?
I was reading that "text" type is just an alias to varchar. Is varchar length only 255 or it can be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TEXT column in your database ( about 64KB characters).

As you know String in java has 2^31-1 characters

Comment: On Cassandra 2.0.16 I can happily insert a text object of 1MB without any data loss.

Comment: What is the limit of TEXT type in Cassandra 3.x?