# How to specify column length on table creation in cql?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

so in SQL I can do the following to specify needed length:

```
CREATE TABLE ... name VARCHAR(**255**) ...
```

Is there some way to do it in CQL? In documentation there is no word about it (or maybe I'm missing something important), so I think it's not possible, but I also didn't find confirmation of it. And what is the maximum length of varchar type in CQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290391/max-length-of-varchar-text-in-cassandra

Comment: Also see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html

Comment: thanks @SimonFontanaOscarsson, but my first and main question is more specific about possibility of specifying column length,

as for second question - 65535 is the maximum length, am I right here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cassandra VARCHAR is just an alias for TEXT data type which stores UTF-8 encoded string. The max size of a string is limit4ed by the max size for a string in Java which is 2147483647 characters (2^31 - 1). You can't set a max string length in table definition for string datatypes.